# Why does combining strings inside a numpy matrix truncate the strings?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have two matrices and need to combine the strings inside

Essentially doing matrix multiplication but with undefined variables hence using strings as matrix multiplication doesn't work with undefined variables

```
import numpy as np

matrixA=np.matrix([
    ['(1)','(1/b)'], 
    ['(-1/b)','(1/b)'] 
]) #defines matrix A

part1Vertices=np.matrix([
    ['(a)','(a)'], #first node/vertex
    ['(a)','(-a)'], #second node
    ['(-a)','(-a)'], #third node 
    ['(-a)','(a)'], #fourth node
    ['(a)','(a)'] #connects fourth node to first
])#defines the shape specified in part 1

print("Part 1 Original: ")#show original values
print(part1Vertices)

for i in range(0,len(part1Vertices):
        val1=np.char.add(np.char.add(np.char.add(matrixA[0][0,0],'*'),part1Vertices[i][0,0]),'+')
        val2=np.char.add(np.char.add(np.char.add(matrixA[1][0,0],'*'),part1Vertices[i][0,1]),'+')
        val3=np.char.add(np.char.add(matrixA[1][0,0],'*'),part1Vertices[i][0,0])
        val4=np.char.add(np.char.add(matrixA[0][0,1],'*'),part1Vertices[i][0,1])
        temp1=np.char.add(val1,val3)
        temp2=np.char.add(val2,val4)
        aList[j][i][0]=temp1,temp2

print("Part 1 Updated: ")#show updated values
print(part1Vertices)
```

Outputs:

```
Part 1 Original: 
[['(a)' '(a)']
 ['(a)' '(-a)']
 ['(-a)' '(-a)']
 ['(-a)' '(a)']
 ['(a)' '(a)']]

Part 1 Updated: 
[['(1)*' '(-1/']
 ['(1)*' '(-1/']
 ['(1)*' '(-1/']
 ['(1)*' '(-1/']
 ['(1)*' '(-1/']]
```

Intended Output:

```
Part 1 Original: 
[['(a)' '(a)']
 ['(a)' '(-a)']
 ['(-a)' '(-a)']
 ['(-a)' '(a)']
 ['(a)' '(a)']]

Part 1 Updated: 
[['(1)*(a)+(1/b)*(a)', '(-1/b)*(a)+(1/b)*(a)']
 ['(1)*(a)+(1/b)*(-a)', '(-1/b)*(a)+(1/b)*(-a)']
 ['(1)*(-a)+(1/b)*(-a)', '(-1/b)*(-a)+(1/b)*(-a)']
 ['(1)*(-a)+(1/b)*(a)', '(-1/b)*(-a)+(1/b)*(a)']
 ['(1)*(a)+(1/b)*(a)', '(-1/b)*(a)+(1/b)*(a)']]
```

Unsure of why this occurring

Comment: Numpy string arrays have a specific length for each string, because numpy arrays are stored as continuous blocks of memory. Since you're calculating the result by iterating in python anyway, why not use a plain old list instead of a numpy array?

Comment: A copy-n-paste of your code does not run; I can't reproduce or improve your code.

Comment: This list comprehension produces what you want: `[[f'{i}*{j}+{k}*{l}' for i,k in matrixA.tolist()] for j,l in part1Vertices.tolist()]`.  I'm converting the matrices to lists of lists (better for iteration), and using string formatting to combine substrings.  `numpy` does not help with this task.